# ogr2ogr reprojection fails, QGIS works

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, ogr2ogr

I need to convert a geopackage in EPSG:5070 to EPSG:4326.  I am using ogr2ogr command but it is telling me, I believe, that certain polygons cannot be translated (see error below).

Here is ogr2ogr command and resulting console output using ogr2ogr version GDAL 3.5.0, released 2022/05/10.  This is on my local mac (Monterey 12.6) laptop,

```
ogr2ogr -f GPKG sample177_4326.gpkg -s_srs EPSG:5070 -t_srs EPSG:4326 sample177_5070.gpkg
ERROR 1: Point outside of projection domain
ERROR 1: Point outside of projection domain
```

Our AWS ubuntu ec2 with ogr2ogr GDAL 3.3.3, released 2021/10/25 gives the following console output.

```
ogr2ogr -f GPKG sample177_4326.gpkg -s_srs EPSG:5070 -t_srs EPSG:4326 sample177_5070.gpkg 
ERROR 1: Unknown error 2050
ERROR 1: Unknown error 2050
ERROR 1: Unknown error 2050
ERROR 1: Unknown error 2050
ERROR 1: Unknown error 2050
ERROR 1: Unknown error 2050
ERROR 1: Unknown error 2050
ERROR 1: Unknown error 2050
ERROR 1: Unknown error 2050
ERROR 1: Unknown error 2050
ERROR 1: Unknown error 2050
ERROR 1: Unknown error 2050
ERROR 1: Unknown error 2050
ERROR 1: Unknown error 2050
ERROR 1: Unknown error 2050
ERROR 1: Unknown error 2050
ERROR 1: Unknown error 2050
ERROR 1: Unknown error 2050
ERROR 1: Unknown error 2050
ERROR 1: Reprojection failed, err = 2050, further errors will be suppressed on the transform object.
ERROR 1: Full reprojection failed, but partial is possible if you define OGR_ENABLE_PARTIAL_REPROJECTION configuration option to TRUE
ERROR 1: Failed to reproject feature 15398 (geometry probably out of source or destination SRS).
ERROR 1: Terminating translation prematurely after failed
translation of layer out (use -skipfailures to skip errors)
ERROR 1: sqlite3_exec(CREATE TRIGGER "trigger_insert_feature_count_out" AFTER INSERT ON "out" BEGIN UPDATE gpkg_ogr_contents SET feature_count = feature_count + 1 WHERE lower(table_name) = lower('out'); END;) failed: no such table: main.out
ERROR 1: sqlite3_exec(CREATE TRIGGER "trigger_delete_feature_count_out" AFTER DELETE ON "out" BEGIN UPDATE gpkg_ogr_contents SET feature_count = feature_count - 1 WHERE lower(table_name) = lower('out'); END;) failed: no such table: main.out
```

I tried to reproject in QGIS (Version | Data Management Tools | Reproject Layer...) and the conversion completes successfully.  I did choose, under advance options, to copy both the python and qgis_process commands and these are below.

QGIS version: 3.26.3-Buenos Aires
Python command:

```
processing.run("native:reprojectlayer", {'INPUT':'/private/tmp/sample177.gpkg|layername=out','TARGET_CRS':QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:4326'),'OPERATION':'+proj=pipeline +step +inv +proj=aea +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +step +proj=unitconvert +xy_in=rad +xy_out=deg','OUTPUT':'ogr:dbname=\'/private/tmp/sample177_4326.gpkg\' table="output" (geom)'})
```

qgis_process command

```
qgis_process run native:reprojectlayer --distance_units=meters --area_units=m2 --ellipsoid=EPSG:7019 --INPUT='/private/tmp/sample177.gpkg|layername=out' --TARGET_CRS='EPSG:4326' --OPERATION='+proj=pipeline +step +inv +proj=aea +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +step +proj=unitconvert +xy_in=rad +xy_out=deg' --OUTPUT=TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
```

Does anyone know why this error is happening in ogr2ogr?
I would like to process this using ogr2ogr and am hoping someone can decipher the QGIS projection options into ogr2ogr format so ogr2ogr works.

The sample data is at https://www.dropbox.com/s/fhapjjd3aciftp3/sample177_5070.gpkg?dl=0

Comment: Thanks for reply.   The "ERROR 1: Point outside of projection domain" is confusing as both the source CRS of EPSG:5070 (North America) and EPSG:4326 (Worldwide) encompass the sample data.   I also get all 16,870 features and they are valid, simple, and the 4326 projection.   I did reproject these using java JTS.transform() and will probably end up using that.

Comment: Still having issues here.   Although the ogr2ogr conversion returns all the polys in 4326 the result has 15,774 holes and 29,122 overlaps in it.   I cannot have either in the result.   I, unfortunately, am seeing the same when converting in QGIS.   So is there no way to convert a geopackage in EPSG:5070 to EPSG:4326 without adding a bunch of holes and overlaps?

Comment: How did you find the holes/overlaps? I'm not seeing them.  Does projecting to NAD83 geographic (EPSG:4269) and then projecting that to EPSG:4326 make any difference?

Comment: We have a custom hole/overlap detector.  I do not find holes in the posted 5070 geopackage, I have attempted conversions from this 5070 geopackage to 4326, 4269, and from 5070 to 4369 to 4326.   In all cases the holes appear.   To see the holes you need to zoom to scale 100:1 (super close), there are gaps between the polygons on certain edges.   After converting to 4326, look at the far right (east) edge where polygon with fid=13221 meets polygon with fid=13083, see [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/a1u4pxldbnz2jss/hole_between_13083_and_13221.png?dl=0) for edge location.